# Facebook login is not working with screen set to Portrait in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login

I am developing a game with Unity. In this game I have a facebook login and I am using facebook SDK version 7.9.4, and unity version 5.6.3f1. I need to set the screen in game. Some scenes need to be played as landscape, and some need to played as portrait. I am using

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

code for portrait set up and

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape
```

code for landscape set up.

The problem is, when the portrait code kicks in the facebook login is not working for iOS. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think this is a bug in the new unity as at this time, use unity 5.6.0f3. it will solve this problem.